# Epiphany doubled capital letters

Tags: keyboard, epiphany

I've switched to Epiphany from Vivaldi few days ago and I'm a bit confused, because every time I start a sentence (It means that I use capital letter ;) - I know some people don't stick to this grammar rule) eg. in facebook message box, I get doubled capital letter ('KK', 'LL' etc.).

I've noticed that it's connected with SHIFT key, because it doubles ?, ", _ too.

Any suggestions how to repair that? 
I'd be grateful for help! :)

Comment: If you can give me some time, I will find the links for you. This is a bug, I think in GTK, if I am not mistaken. It is fixed in the 3.22 version, and I actually just returned here to check in, to see if we could add some pressure to get this fix into Loki now, rather than later.

Answer (score 2):

https://bugzilla.gnome.org/show_bug.cgi?id=764653

I think this should answer most questions.

Comment: Can you please give a summary of the explanation from the link? Link-only answers are generally considered as not being sufficient.

Comment: I will do the best I can.